# Using a library created using rosbuild_add_library

Tags: ros, package.xml, manifest.xml, target-link-libraries, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have created a package in ROS which contains my own header files and I have created a library using these header files using `rosbuild_add_library` (`add_library` in case of Catkin) . I wish to make use of this library in another ROS package. Is it enough to add the package ( containing my library ) to the list of dependency in package.xml (or manifest.xml) of the current package and using `target_link_libraries( my_target  my_library)` in CMakeLists.txt or do I have to specify the complete path to my library?  In other words, do I have to use `link_directories(library_directories)` even after adding my former package to the package.xml of the current package?

`Pkg1` (package) contains a library `foo`. The library has been created using `rosbuild_add_library` on one computer and using `add_library` (for catkin) on another computer. `Pkg2` is the package (created in both computers) in which I want to use the library `foo`.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/194255/using-a-library-created-using-rosbuild_add_library/) by [Hemu](https://answers.ros.org/users/4541/hemu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 156 on 2014-10-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2014-10-06**:
Does `Pkg2` use rosbuild or catkin? Why do you have two versions of `Pkg1` on two different computers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For fuerte you have to add to your manifest.xml of the lib package:

```
 <export>
  <cpp cflags="-I${prefix}/include"
        lflags="-Wl,-rpath,${prefix}/lib -L${prefix}/lib -lyour_lib"/>
  </export>
```

if your headers are placed in the include subfolder for the lib package and the library you creates using `rosbulid_add_library` is named your_lib like:

```
rosbuild_abb_library( your_lib src1.cpp src2.cpp )
```

Your your depenign packages will be automatically compiled against the headers and linked against the lib.

Note:
For catkin (groovy and above) the workaround is slightly different. You do not need this in the package.xml but have to use the catkin_package cmake comand in the CMakeLists.txt of your lib package.........

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2014-10-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hemu](https://answers.ros.org/users/4541/hemu/) on 2014-10-06**:
It worked. I will try using catkin_package command in CMakeLists for the packages built using catkin.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Adding a `rosbuild_add_library` generated library to your package.xml won't work because `rosbuild_add_library` is rosbuild and package.xml is Catkin. Catkin packages can't depend on rosbuild packages.

---

Originally posted by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) with karma: 2949 on 2014-10-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hemu](https://answers.ros.org/users/4541/hemu/) on 2014-10-06**:
I work with fuerte. So, it is manifest.xml. I just wanted a general idea whether the mentioned way of using the library in another package would work or not. Anyway, I will edit the question.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-10-06**:
Please specify precisely in your original question what the dependent and depending packages are (catkin/rosbuild).